# What if n_samples and size_input do not match in fftw implementation

Tags: c++, fftw

I am using fftw3 lib for computing a fourier transform in c++. I have to repeatedly call it with a different input array everytime. I am initializing my array (called 'input' in code ) just once with size MAX_ELEMS and then using it as input to the fftw_plan function (changing contents and their size) on every call. However I am changing my n_samples everytime according to actual size of my array (number of valid data samples in the array). I wanted to know if this will cause any problems in my implementation- execution/accuracy wise.

```
fftw_plan fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(int n_samples,
                                double *in, fftw_complex *out,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you want to pick a specific size of FFT and stick with it, for two reasons:

- creating/destroying plans takes a lot of time relative to the FFT itself, so you're throwing away any speed advantage from using FFTW if you create/destroy a plan for evert FFT you perform
- the frequency resolution will be different for each different size of FFT, which could make interpretation of successive output data troublesome.

Ideally you should use a fixed FFT size so that you create/destroy a plan just once.

If your data stream is contiguous then just pick an appropriate FFT size, N, and accumulate samples in a buffer until you have N samples to process, and save the rest until you have N samples again.

If your data is *not* contiguous then pick a reasonable size FFT, N, and then when you get < N samples you can pad the input with zeroes. When you get > N samples you can discard the extra samples.

In all cases of course you must apply a suitable window function prior to the FFT.

Comment: Paul R: But my array contents are changing on every iteration and fftw_plan takes array as input? How do I solve that. As in the first (and only) time I initialize a plan, what input array do I pass?

Comment: You just re-use the same buffer(s) - it doesn't matter that the contents have changed each time you execute the FFT.

Comment: Ok. I did that. Initialized all arrays in header file of my class. Then when I initialize the object of that class, I assign space, define size and make ffftw plans.Then every time I need the fourier transform I execute plans (with measure flag on). Now I am getting the following segmentation fault. http://pastebin.com/sYs0YA3z. Any idea where I am going wrong. And this is happening during initialization, even before I call the execute methods.

Comment: Solved. Thanks! I was doing one very small mistake, passing size 0 to plan. Overlooked it for 3 hours! :(